# JavaScript NodeList Object styles

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 divs on my html page all of which were assigned a classname 'tagline'. i wanted to assign styles to each of these divs through JavaScript. but NodeList object wont allow me to do the same just like that, i think. her's what i tried. please help me do the same.

```
var taglines = document.getElementsByClassName("tagline");
taglines[0].styles.color = red; //didn't work
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things.

1. you need to put red in quotes like `'red'`
2. it's style (singular) not styles (plural):

   ```
   taglines[0].style.color = 'red';
   ```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WKpbp/)**